# How to link data from DB3 to excel?

Tags: database, microsoft-excel-2016, sql, sqlite

The .db3 database download daily data from the web and I need to analyze those data using an excel file.

the file I use to set the analysis must be an excel file because I use data coming from different sources, one of which is this .db3 file.

How can I link data from this database?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2016

Comment: [How can I access a SQLite database in Microsoft Excel](//stackoverflow.com/q/1630035)